# Grab checkbox values before form submission

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following loop, which shows a checkbox along with an answer (which is grabbed from Wordpress):

```
$counter = 1; 
foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
   <?php echo $row['answer'];
} ?>
```

This is part of a bigger loop that loops through a set of questions and for each question it loops through the answers (code above).

**How can I grab the checkboxes that the user has checked and display the values within a div before the form is submitted?**

I know I can use the following to check if the checkbox is checked:

```
$('form #mycheckbox').is(':checked');
```

I'm not sure where to start with all the looping!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
$.each("#mycheckbox:checked", function() {
    $("div").append(this.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like below:

```
var divContent = "";
$("form input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
   divContent += this.value + "<br/>";
});
$("div").html(divContent);
```

Not completely clear to me when this should be executed. From your question it looks to me like that should happen when user clicks on submit button, in such case you just need to place that code into `$("form").submit(function(){...});`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it needs to be before submission as it's acting as a summary page of what they've clicked before they send it.

Comment: Well, in that case it is better to show like another page with PHP. In this case you do not need any jquery. Or, you may put some button like "End Test". Click on it will hide a form and show that summary div where checkboxes data will be shown with submit and back buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="answer"]');

$('#myDiv').empty();

boxes.on('change', function() {
    boxes.filter(':checked').each(function(i, box) {
        $('#myDiv').append(box.value);
    });
});
```

Get all the matching checkboxes, and whenever one of the checkboxes changes update a div with the values of the checked boxes.

Comment: Is it possible to have a bit more info with what is happening here?

Comment: @Rob - I'll try to explain it? I see you've mentioned before submission, but when someone hits the submit button, it's a bit late to be adding content to elements, as the page is about to reload.

Comment: This will update the div with id `myDiv` whenever the checkboxes are changed, probably a preferred solution rather then doing this on submission.

Answer (score 0):

The loop you provide is happening server side, as it is php code. When you wan't to validate the form **before** submission you must do it on the client, ie using javascript.

So, you will not use the same loop, but rather create a new one that is run when any checkbox is changed.

I suggest you to add a class name to the checkboxes (like `class='cb_answer'`) in the php loop. This will help you to safely select the specific checkboxes when doing the validation.

Here is a script snippet that will add the value of selected checkboxes to a div each time any checkbox is changed. Add this just before `</body>`. May need to modify it to fit your needs.

```
<script>
    // make sure jQuery is loaded...
    $(documet).ready( {
        // when checkboxes are changed...
        $('.cb_answer').on('change', function() {
             // clear preview div...
             $('#answers_preview').html('');
             // loop - all checked checkboxes...
             $('.cb_answer:checked').each(function() {
                 // add checkbox value to preview div...
                 $('#answers_preview').append(this.val());
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```

assuming `id='answers_preview'` for the div to preview the answers and `class='cb_answer'` for the checkboxes.